# Remove all -es/-s/-e/-x suffixes that follow 4 or more characters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to delete all word suffixes `-es`, `-s`, `-e` or `-x` of all words that have at least 4 characters after removing the suffix, using regex in Python.

There are some examples of desired output *(in French)*:

- technologiqu**es** → technologiqu
- pare**s** → pare    *(the word is too small so it does not remove the "es", only the "s")*
- bas → bas    *(the word is too small so it does not do anything)*
- matériau**x** → materiau
- sièg**es** → sieg
- sieg**e** → sieg
- feuilleté**es** → feuilleté
- dos → dos

---

I tried to implement as shown below, but I do not find it very efficient.

```
def _stem_reg(word):
    pattern = "(\w{4,})(es$)|(\w{4,})(s$)|(\w{4,})(e$)|(\w{4,})(x$)"
    found = re.match(pattern, word)

    if found is not None:
        return next(group for group in found.groups() if group is not None)
    else:
        return word
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not very efficient"?

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'\b(\w{4,})(?:e?s|[ex])\b', r'\1', s)`

Comment: What about the accent sign in `sièges`?

Comment: @Dominique - the Unicode pattern `[^\W\d_]` matches also accent sign characters such as `è`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: [`^(\w{4,}?)(?:es|s|e|x)$`](https://regex101.com/r/yRqlV9/1)

```
word = "feuilletées"
output = re.sub(r"^(\w{4,}?)(?:es|s|e|x)$", r'\1', word)
```

- `(\w{4,}?)` capturing group 1 will match 4 or more letters.
- `(?:es|s|e|x)` non-capturing group will match all the postfix's that are in scope (-es, -s, -e, -x)

Comment: Pattern `(\w{4,}?)` would match not just letters, but also numbers and underscore, so for example it will match a string `X7_q`

Answer (score -2):

Assuming

```
txt = "your input string"
```

You can use:

```
re.sub(r"\b([^\W\d_]{4,})(?:(?<=...[^e])s|(?<=^...e)s|es|e|x)\b", r'\1', txt, flags = re.U)
```

---

Test this regex pattern [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/XsGEtl/2).